# Scale RAM of a Azure VM like Virtual Disk

Tags: azure

I would like to host a windows ND24r-VM in Azure which is of 448 GB RAM initially. Is it possible to scale up the RAM alone from 448 to higher as required?  I've just been having a quick look at the pricing calculator and there seems to be a gap between 448GB and the next available VM of 1000GB.  Therefore is it possible to scale up in 100GB units **of RAM alone** during times of heavy load?

Comment: For now, Azure does not support scale memory, you should resize that VM to change memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot scale memory like storage or a virtual disk. Azure Virtual Machines are configured with certain compute, memory and networking bandwidth.

To get more memory you will need to chose a different instance type.

Comment: I hope if Azure support this, it would be better